# Zend Framework - Issue with delete from database code

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

In my `Application_Model_DbTable_User`, I have the following function:

```
public function deleteUser($username)
{
    $this->delete('username = ' . (string) $username);
}
```

This function is being called from my `AdminController`, with this three lines of code.

```
$uname = $this->getRequest()->getParam('username');
$user = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
$user->deleteUser($uname);
```

This error however, turns up.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause'

With test being the user I am trying to delete.

This code is adapted from a previous code which deletes based on `id`, a INT field, which works perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong? I would be happy to give more detailed codes if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query isn't quoted:

```
$this->delete('username = ' . (string) $username);
```

This equates to:

```
WHERE username = test
```

If you use the where() method, it will do this for you:

```
$table->where('username = ?', $username);
```

Or (like the example in the docs):

```
$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('bug_id = ?', 1235);
$table->delete($where);
```

Comment: it's better like that : $db = $this->getAdapter(); $table->where($db->quoteInto('username = ?', $username));